# AWS EC2 not delivering website after instance size change

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

My webserver on AWS was running on a `m1.large` instance. Since it doesn't have much load I wanted to downgrade it to save some money.

Therefore I stopped the instance and then went to: `Instance Settings` -> `Change Instance Type`, changed that to `m1.medium`

After that I started that instance again. I'm able to connect to the instance using ssh and therefore I can see, that all the files are in the proper place. Still I only get a blank (white) page, when I try to load the website.

Any Ideas what to do to bring the website back up?

Note: I have never before changed an instance size or shut one down on AWS to reboot it then. Is there a trick I have to take care of?

Comment: could it be as simple as starting apache? "sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start"

Comment: Its likely a service did not start on reboot.

Comment: Changing instance type should not impact what your instance is doing. It's more likely that the reboot caused a change, or a service is not running on startup. Can you login to the instance and inspect the web server? By the way, m1.medium is a rather old instance type. You would get better performance from the m3 family.

Comment: @Finbarr you where absolutely right, it was only apache, that didn't start. thanks!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I know, that m1 is from the last generation of EC2, but as I understood it, they are cheaper than the m3, so why use m3 then?

Comment: @wawa m3 is actually cheaper than m1. An m1.medium Linux in USA is 8.7c/hr, with 1 vCPU (2 ECU) and 3.75 GiB RAM. An m3.medium has 1 vCPU (3 ECU) and 3.75 GiB RAM, for a cost of 7c/hr. So, it has a 50% more powerful CPU and is 1.7c/hr cheaper. (ECU = Elastic Compute Unit, which is a relative measure of computing power)

Comment: Have you checked the public ip of the instance did not change?

Comment: @Mike there are 2 servers behind a Loadbalancer, I'm not sure, if they both have a public ip.

Comment: If you go to the load balancer page are they showing up as in service or out of service? There is a weird issue with the load balancers where if an instance is turned off the lb will consider it out of service and stop checking, so even if it comes back online the lb will keep it marked as offline, to solve, remove from the lb, then re add.

Comment: Just fyi you can check an instance's ip(s) by going to the ec2 instances page and selecting an instance, the properties tab at the bottom of the page will definitely show a private IP and depending how you set it up a public one as well. The reason I was asking was that its possible to point a dns hostname directly at a public IP which could have changed on restart. If you are using a loadbalancer though there is no need to have a public IP, it only needs a private one which never changes.